# Implementing StickyGridHeaders

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview and I am trying to add headers for different categories. (I have 4 categories so I want to implement four headers). Now all the items in the 4 categories loading to one same grid.

I tried this instructions but it didn't work for me ([Using StickyGridHeaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802098/using-stickygridheaders)), any help for me to implement this category headers will be appreciated.

PizzaFragment class

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_grid_main, container, false);
        new PizzaMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), this).execute();

        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {
        try {
            List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);
                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("2") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("8") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("9") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }
            }
            CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), descriptions, imageUrls);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

CustomGrid class

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
    private final List<String> descriptions;
    private final List<String> imageUrls;
    public CustomGrid(Context c, List<String> descriptions, List<String> imageUrls) {
        this.context = c;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return descriptions.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return descriptions.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_pizza, parent, false);
            holder.ivImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvHeader.setText(descriptions.get(position));
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(imageUrls.get(position)).into(holder.ivImage);
        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvHeader;
        private ImageView ivImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this questions is old but I hope this can help someone.

change gridview in yourlayout.xml to custom gridview from stickygridheaders

```
<com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/asset_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:columnWidth="90dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dip"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dip" />
```

create xml for your header. example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#ff33b5e5"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

implements StickyGridHeadersSimpleAdapter in your custom adapter

you can view example in  [here](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders)

Comment: hi brother . i've implemented this library .but my header is still following `A` header with `A` dataitem logic . can you explain how to change that ?